# How to sum the pivot item data based on condition using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, pivot-table

```
ParentName    Designation    offsite      onsite   total
ASP           ASE                 1                    1
              SE                  2           2        4
              ITA                 3           7       10
              AssSE               **2**           2        4
ASP Total                         8          11       19
ESP           ITA                15                   15
              AssC                2                    2
              AssSE               1                    1
ESP Total                        18                   18
IS-TP         ASE                 7                    7
              AssSE             **19**                   19
              SE                 32                   32
              BA                  1           3        4
              ITA                24          11       35
IS-TP Total                      83          14       97
Grand Total                     109          25      134
```

***In that pivot table the star marked cell values can be summed based on the pivot data. How to get the pivot data and sum the values based on the designation. i.e. if designation is Asst.system engineer and Parent IOU Name is "Is-Telecom-parent" and Assurance Services-1Parent then get the offsite total count and summed them as resultant in excel using VBA.***

**Provide VBA code

Comment: Can't you simply modify the pivot or create a second pivot - with 'Designation' as the first row field? Alternatively, try this formula: `=SUMIFS($C:$C,$B:$B,"AsstSystems Engineer")`

Comment: in some pivot table other parent name rather than ASP and IS-TP have AsstSystems Engineer. But i need only summed data from ASP and IS-TP offsite values

Comment: If you need this in VBA, you can still use the SUMIFS formula: `strSearch = "AsstSystemsEngineer"): Debug.Print WorkhseetFunction.Sumifs(Range("C:C"),Range("B:B"),strSearch)`

Comment: hi peter thanks. but i need the AssSE offsite value from only parent name must be IS-Tp and ASP. Now i edited the data. please see the change data for that only i need it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Sub SumSelectedPivotElements()
    Dim piv As PivotTable
    Dim res As Double

    Set piv = Sheets("YourSheet").PivotTables(1) 'Replace with correct sheetname

    'Replace "Location" with your column field name
    res = piv.GetPivotData("Name of your data field", "ParentName", "IS-TP", "Designation", "AssSE", "Location", "offsite")
    res = res + piv.GetPivotData("Name of your data field", "ParentName", "IS-TP", "Designation", "AssSE", "Location", "offsite")
    Debug.Print "The result is: ", res
End Sub
```

Comment: k thanks..peter i need based on conditions check for parentname. because if i use the above code its not work for another data in which IS-TP has only AssSE. i need which ever excel dat i give based on parent name it works.